# Cannot run bpftrace from docker executor

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci-runner, bpf, bpftrace

I'm trying to run `bpftrace` on gitlab runner. Bpftrace should start in job which is `docker` executor.  In `config.toml` file I set cap_add and privileged options and I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unknown error -1: couldn't set RLIMIT_MEMLOCK for bpftrace. If your program is not loading, you can try "ulimit -l 8192" to fix the problem
stdin:1:1-34: ERROR: tracepoint not found: raw_syscalls:sys_enter
tracepoint:raw_syscalls:sys_enter { @[comm] = count(); }
```

When I ssh to gitlab runner and start bpftrace it works normally.

In config.toml file I set cap_add and privileged options and I run bpftrace with sudo. When I run same bpftrace command in `.gitlab-ci.yml` I get error.